# How many vars should there be in a cookie?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies, curl

While using cURL with some site, I noticed that some files that I requested actually used several variables from the cookie I set up with curl.

Here's a snapshot:

[image]

But when I check my cookie file all it reads is just one value for **ASP.NET_SessionId**:

```
www.*******.***  FALSE  /  FALSE  0  ASP.NET_SessionId  ddj24l55lfu11nb1lhuflw55
```

Of course, the values from the snapshot are taken from my browser (Internet Explorer F12), and that cookie contains Three variables (not one).
Internet Explorer F12 cookie variables Name/Values:

```
NAME  ASPSESSIONIDSACRDADD 
VALUE  LOONCEMDHCGEJOANEGHHFAFH 

NAME  ASPSESSIONIDSCBRABDC 
VALUE  CMONJEMDNICPNPNFICLAPMFM 

NAME  ASPSESSIONIDQACSBADC 
VALUE  MCBOGLCCKNIDDBOADNMPCLCD
```

this is my CURL settings for cookies:

```
$cookiefile = "d:/cookie.txt";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
```

What is it that I may be missingin cURL ?

Thanks!

Comment: When were those cookies *received*? They're probably stale cookies of old sessions still hanging around that the browser is sending out, but that the server is not actually interested in anymore. Are these cookies being *set* anywhere when looking at the browser tools?

Comment: couldn't be more correct. Thank you so much. I cleared the cache and I am back to one cookie back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the nature of the div collection, it looks to be like variables are from different browser sessions.

And Even if its not, its up to developer on how to create your application to set and read the data.